# Percent of Apex Used: Do spaces count?

Tags: apex, limits

The limit on the amount of characters you can have in Apex is 3,000,000. I understand that comments and test classes do not count towards this limit. Another developer just asked me if the space character counts and I could not answer with certainty. I hope that someone out there can tell me that they do not count against the character limit.

Comment: They won't if they're inside comments though.

Comment: This is a very good point!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A quick test would suggest that they do...

Here is a simple class in my DE

[image: simple class]

and the code usage

[image: usage1]

If I add loads of characters, the usage goes up..

[image: duff characters]

[image: usage 2]

when I removed them, it went back down, now I added loads of white space, and the usage climbed again:

[image: white space]

[image: usage 3]

And this is chaining lots of spaces together, so I would say that lots of individual spaces in real code will behave the same way..!

It even counts spaces at the end of a line, as you can see here:

[image: end of line]

[image: usage 5]

It **does** also count the spaces at the start of a line (the indentation)

BUT

It **does not** appear to count spaces in lines containing nothing but spaces though!

Comment: Did you test extra spaces at the end of a line?

Comment: I did not... but just for you @sfdcfox please see the edit ;)

Comment: and an interesting revelation in the last line of the answer regarding lines containing nothing BUT spaces..

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to figure that out, Simon. We try to keep our code formatted for readability but I guess we'll just need to keep it ugly as we get close to our character limit.

Comment: Tabs also counts 1 towards character limits, so it could be useful to use tabs instead of 4 spaces.

Comment: hopefully this is changed soon. It is absurd and hurts best practices such as code stylin/formatting. 

Most fair indicator would to be base the limit on generated byte code (assuming Apex runs on the JVM)

Comment: I very much doubt it will be changed; it is effectively just the file size really and discounting spaces would be a huge effort in SF part! It is incredibly simple to request more Apex space off Salesforce so long as you have a legitimate reason to do so via a support case, incidentally.